# Probability based on a statement being probable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Question: “Get slapped once every three times you visit her” is a famous quote about Angry Granny. Andrew is one of her servants and visits her 15 times every day. What is the probability that Andrew would be slapped 13 times in a week if we believe that the quote mentioned above is correct? How would your answer change if the probability of the quotes being true is 0.9?

Now I know the first part of this question can be solved using Binomial distribution, out of total n=15*7 times he visit the Granny, we have to find probability of r=13 where p=1/3.

But I cannot figure out how do we find the changed probability if the quote is true with probability only 0.9. I know it is conditional probability but what is the exact expression we are trying to find out here?

Comment: That has not been stated in the problem. Yes I get that law of total probability can be used if we are given the probability of slap if the statement is not true.

Comment: Hmmm, should we perhaps assume that the probability of slap is zero if the statement is not true?

Comment: In that case, it simply would not contribute to the answer

Comment: Yes, ok. But if we do not know it we cannot proceed since P(slap)=P(slap|true)P(true)+P(slap|false)P(false)=(1/3)(0.9)+P(slap|false)(0.1), or not?

Comment: absolutely right, I had that in mind but dropped the idea since P(slap|false) is not known.